# Sudden drop in free memory on EC2 instance at about 6 am daily

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, memory-usage, memory-leak

I have been noticing for a few months, pretty much since I set up a server on AWS, that my instance experiences a sudden drop in free memory at regular times, about 6am UTC, almost every day. It's a t2.nano instance, more than sufficient for my needs. There is no unusual activity at that time, usually no connections being made to the server (it's a modest personal site). I've created a server watching Python script to record this and to restart the server when memory drops:

```
2016-12-08 06:14:30,971 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:16:31,096 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:18:31,231 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:20:31,365 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:22:31,499 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:24:31,634 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 280 MB
2016-12-08 06:26:31,822 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 44 MB
2016-12-08 06:26:31,822 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Server restarted
2016-12-08 06:27:09,751 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Server Watcher starting up
2016-12-08 06:29:09,905 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 281 MB
2016-12-08 06:31:10,058 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 281 MB
2016-12-08 06:33:10,209 - AWS_Server_Watcher - INFO: Free memory: 281 MB
```

Does anyone know what happens? I suspect it's something to do with the EC2 infrastructure, out of my control. But I'm not signed up to a paid support plan with AWS, so I can't ask them about it.

Comment: IMHO opinion, i think it has to do with how they manage memory in t2 instances, because you are based on credits, your memory probably drops when you run low (similar to cpu), or you stay idle and some of the memory is reallocated to other busy instances/neighbors. Post a ticket to AWS and let us know as well.

Comment: Check /etc/cron.daily

Comment: @Orphans: I think you're on to something, `/var/log/syslog.1` shows (I've edited the IP for security): `Dec  8 06:25:01 ip-180-30-0-334 CRON[11495]: (root) CMD (test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily ))
Dec  8 06:25:57 ip-180-30-0-334 rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="987" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] rsyslogd was HUPed`. Then in `syslog` first line ends with `rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="7.4.4" x-pid="987" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] exiting on signal 15.` What is HUPed, is that the culprit?

Comment: This `rsyslogd was HUPed` seems to be a normal operation. Happens when the logfile is rotated by `logrotate`.

Comment: AWS don't mess with the RAM, that's all under the control of the operating system. They can't even tell from the hypervisor how much RAM is used/free. Cron or any operating system processes, admin processes from software you run, etc. What software is running on the machine?

Comment: @Tim: I am glad to hear that AWS isn't the culprit, but how do you know? Is this written up somewhere? Anyway, I agree, I think the cause is in the OS. The software is Apache, Proftpd, Postfix and Dovecot, on a Ubuntu Server. I don't suspect any of these as their logs show nothing unusual. The daily cron using rsyslogd coincides though, it runs just before the drop in memory. I've done some searches, and there are reports of bugs in rsyslogd on Ubuntu, but nothing to conclusively tie it to my problem. My setup is quite standard, I'm surprised there aren't more reports like mine.

Comment: I know that AWS has no visibility into how the OS uses RAM because you have to run a custom CloudWatch metric for CloudWatch to graph RAM status. Since AWS controls the hypervisor they could do anything, but everything I've read suggests they don't - and I have three AWS certifications. Since cron is happening around the time of the problem I'd look much more closely at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm surprised there aren't more reports like mine.

That may be because this is normal, expected behavior... but this is not related in any way to AWS.

This is the installed server OS, itself, doing scheduled daily maintenance/background jobs.

You actually got really close before you stopped investigating.

In the file `/etc/crontab`, you'll find this:

```
25 6 * * * root test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

Looks familiar, right (from the syslog message you found)?  Now, take a look at the files in that directory.

```
$ ls /etc/cron.daily

apport  apt  aptitude  bsdmainutils  dpkg  logrotate  man-db  mlocate  
ntp  popularity-contest  update-notifier-common  upstart
```

Each of these scripts runs, one after the other, every day, beginning at 06:25 in whatever time zone the server is configured to use, on essentially every stock Ubuntu machine, everywhere.  There may be exceptions, but I've never used any other Linux disto that didn't have something very similar.

The t2.nano machines, as you know, only have 512 MiB of memory, which is a very small amount of memory for a modern 64-bit OS. But, as you mentioned, they're still perfect for a lot of things.  You may want to add some swap space and potentially make your monitoring a little bit less aggressive, because these are  standard components that I would suggest should not be tinkered with or disabled unless you have a solid understanding of what you are doing.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. I've accepted your answer because I think you're right and this takes us out of the AWS domain specifically, the issue is more about the OS and its hardware requirements and/or bugs. I'm still not quite convinced that cron, even on a 64-bit machine, would require 236MB (280 - 44 MB in my log). It seems excessive. Perhaps all those bash utilities it's using mount up. I'm going to monitor this on my own Linux desktop and see how it compares to the EC2 instance.

Comment: I suspect it is `apt` doing the package database maintenance but it could be any of these jobs. I doubt the memory condition lasts very long, but I think you'll find this fairly easy to validate.  The timing correlates nicely.

Comment: In case it helps anyone else using a t2.nano server: I narrowed the problem down to `apt` and `logrotate` in the daily cron. I disabled the apt updates, as I prefer to do them manually. Logrotate needs about 100 MB, so I coded my server watching script to restart the server at 6am. That frees anough memory for the daily cron, and the server survives to the next 6am with about 70 MB free memory. Problem solved.